# $state.go timing out within $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently trying to check to see if a user is authenticated when the state changes. In my run block I'm listening for `$stateChangeStart` event. In the following code I can currently get the console to log `podio is authenticated` and `podio is not authenticated`, but when i add `$state.go` into the `catch` statement, it loads infinitely and then times out. I've tried adding 'event.preventDefault` as it says [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/969), but I don't fully understand why that would be necessary.

**Run Block**

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {

            ...

            Podio.podio.isAuthenticated()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('podio is authenticated');
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('podio is not authenticated');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('login'); //when this is added it continues to load...
                });
            ...

    });
```

I'm sure it's not the state definitions, because they've been working correctly all along.

**State Definitions**

```
$stateProvider
                // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
                .state('tab', {...})    
                .state('tab.events', {...})
                .state('tab.event-detail',{...})
                .state('tab.attendees',{...})
                .state('tab.attendee-detail',{...})
                .state('login', {
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                });
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what the point authenticate so often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run `isAuthenticated` check on each `stateChangeStart`. If this check fails you end up in `catch` block navigating to some state. This triggers `stateChangeStart` again with failing authentication check.

You can add some flag to `login` state to allow access for unauthenticated users:

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  requireAuthentication: false,
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginController'
})
```

And check it later:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
  ...
  if(!toState.hasOwnProperty('requireAuthentication') || toState.requireAuthentication !== false)
    Podio.podio.isAuthenticated()
  ...
}
```

Comment: This worked greatly! Thanks! Is this a best practice to check on each state change?

Comment: I don't see this as a bad practice if this check does not affect navigation speed. But there is a small problem in such approach: Podio.podio.isAuthenticated() is an asynchronous call. If I load some URL for the first time, this check will not prevent "protected" state from rendering until the promise is resolved. So you need additional URL check on server side for this approach to work - the server should redirect me to login page if I'm not authenticated.